# Problema com efeito em multiplas LIs

Tags: jquery

Tenho 4 `li`, 2 delas ficam aparecendo no site, e outras duas irão aparecer somente quando eu clicar em alguma dessas outras duas, pra vocês entenderem melhor, segue meu código:

```js
$(".membrosClick").click(function() {
  $(".listagemEsc").show();
});
$(".membrosFechar").click(function() {
  $(".listagemEsc").hide();
});
```

```css
.membros {
  position: relative;
  width: 1120px
}
.membros li {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.membros li>div.subir>h2 {
  font-family: "bebasneue_regular";
  font-size: 67.99px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 350px;
  margin-left: 65px;
  height: 59px;
  line-height: 59px;
}
.membros li>div.subir>h3 {
  font-family: "bebasneue_light";
  font-size: 67.99px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 65px;
  height: 59px;
  line-height: 59px;
}
.membros li:hover .barraNone {
  display: block;
}
.membros li:hover .subir {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<li class="editable membrosClick" name="Listagem de Membros" style="background-image: url('./imagens/membro1.jpg'); width:383px; height:849px">
  <div class="subir">
    <h2>Antônio</h2>
    <h3>Guerra</h3> 
  </div>
  <div class="bandaBarra bandaBarraBranca margin-left-65 margin-top-10 barraNone"></div>
</li>
<li class="listagemEsc p-relative">
  <div class="membrosFechar"></div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo.</span>
</li>
<li class="editable membrosClick" name="Listagem de Membros" style="background-image: url('./imagens/membro2.jpg'); width:383px; height:849px">
  <div class="subir">
    <h2>Antônio</h2>
    <h3>Guerra</h3> 
  </div>
  <div class="bandaBarra bandaBarraBranca margin-left-65 margin-top-10 barraNone"></div>
</li>
```

O que deve acontecer:
Quando eu clicar na `li` **membrosClick** a `li` do lado **listagemEsc** deve aparecer.
Ok, isso está acontecendo, só aparecem todas as **listagemEsc** do site.
Eu deveria usar `parent`, `closest`? no Jquery?

Comment: Acho que podes usar `.next()`... `$(".membrosClick").click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});`

Comment: @Sergio era isso mesmo que eu precisava, nota 10!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os `li` são seguidos (siblings/irmãos) podes usar o [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) que seleciona o próximo sibling desse elemento. Exemplo:

```
$(".membrosClick").click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/53zgvwfj/**